# Wordpress 404 issue with certain requests containg the string "admin-"

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, apache

I have a wordpress page that generally works, but tonight, when updating the menu didnt work, I realized that something isn't working. So after choosing which menu items I want to add to the menu and hitting the button "Add to menu" the loading-circle starts to rotate endlesly. After inspecting more details in the developer-console, I see the following:

The GET request to `https://URL/wp-admin/-ajax.php` results in a 404. The `wp-admin/-ajax.php` doesnt look right to me. It should actually be `wp-dmin/admin-ajax.php`. So for some reason the `admin` part gets stripped away.

I notice the same symptom for loading some CSS files:
`https://URL/wp-admin/-bar.min.js` can also not be loaded. I think this should in fact be `admin-bar.min.js`.

My .htaccess looks as follows:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I also already tried to disable all plugins to no avail.

Any hints on what could cause this issue? What can caus removing the `admin` part from these requests?

**EDIT:**
Could the following apache-config be the cause?

```
RedirectMatch permanent /admin(.*) https://konferenzimforum.at/wp-admin/$1
```

Comment: Seems like this might be an overzealous WAF or other security appliance between your client and the server - can you provide a bit more detail on the known network topology between the two? Can you also provide a bit more color as to why you've elected to include your `.htaccess` file here when there are no rules regarding the word "admin" there?

Comment: just updated above. can you please check? thanks!

Comment: about the inclusion of `.htaccess`: i expected people to ask what it looks like, so I simply provided it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Why this happens in your configuration

The configuration line you included from your Apache config file is almost certainly the root cause of this behavior. To understand *why* this is, we must dive just a bit deeper into what the line *actually* does:

```
RedirectMatch permanent
```

Simply enough, this declares a `permanent` (HTTP code 301) redirect based on a RegExp pattern matching operation.

```
/admin(.*)
```

This pattern basically tells Apache, "match any URL that contains `/admin`, followed by any character, any number of times, while *capturing* the text *after* the `/admin` substring into a temporary variable, `$1`".

```
https://konferenzimforum.at/wp-admin/$1
```

This string then takes that earlier-captured value and instructs Apache to redirect the requestor to the URL `https://konferenzimforum.at/wp-admin/`, with the earlier-captured value *appended* to the end.

When this is applied to the URL in your example, `wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` would become `wp-admin/-ajax.php`, because `/admin` triggers the match, then uses the remainder of the URL captured in `$1` as a post-fix, which then creates the non-existent URLs you're seeing in your browser's development tools. You can see a more visual & plain-English representation of how this pattern works in practice by using [this Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/OO4qhK/1/). You'll notice on that page that the part that gets removed in your configuration is highlighted a different color than the part of the URL that gets passed through to the redirected URL.

---

#### How you can resolve it

There are a number of ways to resolve this; the easiest is probably to just remove this rule entirely (as it's not clear based solely on the information in the question why this rule would be necessary in the first place).

Another way to do it would be to ensure that only requests to `/admin/*` are matched, instead of arbitrarily matching all URLs that include a `/admin` sequence (which, as you've seen, can inadvertently target *files* beginning with `/admin`), which seems to be more of what you're trying to do (redirect requests for `/admin` to the appropriate `/wp-admin` resource):

```
RedirectMatch permanent /admin/(.*) https://konferenzimforum.at/wp-admin/$1
```